# PyMYSQL Lock Wait Timeout Exceeded

Tags: mysql, pymysql

When I try to execute a query on PyMySQL I get the following error:

```
pymysql.err.InternalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')t
```

However, if I execute it directly on the server, it works correctly. Further, if I run on the dev database, which is a clone of the production, just different content in the tables, it works fine. How can I go about debugging this so that I can get my Python scripts running correctly again?

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if the database size grows and you perform many transactions on it.  You should probably optimize your queries or modify the timeout:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 10000; 

SET innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 10000;
```

That should help...

Comment: Same issue is persisting when I run 'set innodb_lock_wait_timeout=10000'. Also, in case it helps, this is the only transaction on the database that appears when running show full processlist;